# Task Send an Email page ..Send button is not copying the CC email ids

Tags: case, button

Can any one help me on this ...

We are using the standard functionality of Task "Send an Email page" Send Button for the cases to reply to the customer.When the customers sends a email ,keeping in cc to service team a ticket is raised .when we click on the "Send Email Button" the cc is not getting copied .
Any idea or suggestion what may be the issue.

PFA Screen Shot :
[image]

> Update - VF page constructs URL via controller as:

```
String redUrl = '/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid='+
    cas.contactId+
   '&p26='+cas.Email_to‌​_Case_Address__c +
   '&rtype=003&p3_lkid=' +cas.id + 
   '&p4='+cas.Email_CC_Address__c+
   '&p5='+ cas.Email_BCC_Address__c + 
   '&p6='+subject+ '&retURL=/'+ cas.id ;
```

Portion of VF PAGE :

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="CaseCommentAndEmailPageController">
  <apex:form >
            <apex:messages />
           <apex:pageBlock id="abc">
                <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Add Comment" action="{!addComment}" rendered="{!isButtonVisible}" target="_top" styleClass="btn custBtn"/>
                    <apex:commandLink value="Send Email" action="{!sendEmail}"  rendered="{!isButtonVisible}" styleClass="btn custBtn" target="_top" />
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Portion of Code:**

```
   public PageReference sendEmail(){
   //old Code
        System.debug('Working.....................');
        if(cas.Email_CC_Address__c == null || cas.Email_CC_Address__c == 'null'){
             System.debug('cas.Email_CC_Address__c = '+cas.Email_CC_Address__c);
            cas.Email_CC_Address__c ='';
        }
        if(cas.Email_BCC_Address__c == null || cas.Email_BCC_Address__c == 'null'){
            System.debug('cas.Email_BCC_Address__c = '+cas.Email_BCC_Address__c);
            cas.Email_BCC_Address__c ='';
        }
        System.debug('cas.CaseNumber = '+cas.CaseNumber);
        System.debug('cas.Subject = '+cas.Subject);
        String subject = cas.CaseNumber+' - '+cas.Subject;
        if(subject.length() >= 100){
            subject = subject.subString(0,99);
            System.debug('Sub cas.Subject = '+subject);
        }
        String redUrl = '/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid='+cas.contactId+'&p26='+cas.Email_to_Case_Address__c +'&rtype=003&p3_lkid=' +cas.id +
                         '&p4='+cas.Email_CC_Address__c+'&p5=' + cas.Email_BCC_Address__c + '&p6='+subject+     
                        '&retURL=/'+ cas.id ;
        System.debug('redUrl = '+redUrl );
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor');
         System.debug('End.....................');
         pageRef.getParameters().put('p2_lkid',cas.contactId);
         pageRef.getParameters().put('p26',cas.Email_to_Case_Address__c);
         pageRef.getParameters().put('rtype','003');
         String caseId = cas.id;
         if(caseId != null && caseId.length() > 15){
             pageRef.getParameters().put('p3_lkid',caseId.subString(0,15));
         }
         pageRef.getParameters().put('p4',cas.Email_CC_Address__c);
         pageRef.getParameters().put('p5',cas.Email_BCC_Address__c);
         pageRef.getParameters().put('p6',subject);
         pageRef.getParameters().put('retURL',cas.id);
       // pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
    }
```

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: are you using emailToCase?

Comment: @cropredy:Yes ,we are using email to case .We have a vf page been created and for send email button the url is given as : String redUrl = '/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid='+cas.contactId+'&p26='+cas.Email_to_Case_Address__c +'&rtype=003&p3_lkid=' +cas.id +
                         '&p4='+cas.Email_CC_Address__c+'&p5=' + cas.Email_BCC_Address__c + '&p6='+subject+     
                        '&retURL=/'+ cas.id ; but when we click on the send email button,the CC and Bcc email ids are not getting copied.Any Suggestions very much appreciated.

Comment: so you are not using the Send Email button on the EmailMessage related list?  You have some button on the Case detail page at the Case level? Have you tried manually entering the URL via copy-paste to see if the cc is populated? Does your VF controller get `email_cc_address__c` in context when getRecord() is called?  (It won't unless that field is in the VF markup or you use `addFields()` method

Comment: @cropredy:The SendEmail button at case level.The above url is given at the code end and when i get a email from the customer and i reply to them by clicking the send emailbutton ...when checked in the url https://na32.salesforce.com/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p26=support%40enterprisedb.com&p2_lkid=0033800002bdxoVAAQ&p3_lkid=5003800000lEY7e&p4=&p5=&p6=530027+-+Testing+on+CC+email&retURL=5003800000lEY7eAAG&rtype=003&inline=1 ,the p4 & p5 are not getting copied .i.e cc and bcc email ids are not getting copied out.What may be the issue.Any help veyr much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay

This can be done without a VF controller as follows (Here I used a custom object `Foo__c` rather than `Case` as I didn't want to mess up my Dev Edition `Case`):

```
<apex:page standardController="Foo__c" extensions="FooExtensions">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:variable var="vContact" value="{!Foo__c.contact__c}"/>
        <apex:variable var="vTo" value="{!Foo__c.to__c}"/>
        <apex:variable var="vCc" value="{!Foo__c.cc__c}"/>
        <apex:variable var="vBcc" value="{!Foo__c.bcc__c}"/>
        <apex:variable var="vName" value="{!Foo__c.name}"/>
    <apex:pageMessages />
       <apex:pageBlock id="abc">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
         <apex:commandButton value="New Comment"
            rendered="{!isButtonVisible}" styleClass="btn custBtn"
            action="{!URLFOR('00a/e',null,
                              'parent_id'=Foo__c.id,
                              'retURL'='/'+Foo__c.id)}"/>  
         <apex:commandButton value="Send Email" 
            rendered="{!isButtonVisible}" styleClass="btn custBtn"
            action="{!URLFOR('/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor',$ObjectType.Task,[
                             'p2_lkid'=Foo__c.contact__c,
                             'p26'=Foo__c.to__c,
                             'rtype'='003',
                             'p3_lkid'=Foo__c.id,
                             'p4'=Foo__c.cc__c,
                             'p5'=Foo__c.bcc__c,
                             'p6'=Foo__c.name,
                             'retURL'='/'+foo__c.id                          
                                                       ])}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons
    </apex:pageBlock>

    ... rest of page ...
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

*Notes*

1. The `apex:variable` are needed to fetch values for the various `to, cc, bcc, subject, ...` fields from the controller for use in the `URLFOR`. If your VF page already has these fields elsewhere on the page, the `apex:variable` is not necessary.
2. The `URLFOR` creates the redirect to the new Task `Send an Email` page. If you are not familiar with URLFOR, its syntax can sometimes be confusing.  Just like any other VF function, everything within a `{!..}` is either an expression of constants and/or merge fields. What is sometimes confusing is the URLFOR third parameter, labeled `inputs` [in the VF doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) without any examples (!?!). This third parameter syntax is `expression=expression`

If, for some reason, you have to use a Controller, then be sure that you include the `<apex:variable>` on your page for any field needed by the controller in your expression for `redUrl`.

Comment: :Thanks for your response.As suggested i tried creating the VF page .When i click on the send email button..the send an email page gets opened ,from address and Bcc address it reflects my email id and  its not copying the cc field. What may be the issue.Any Suggestions very much appreciated.

Comment: @SalesforceCRMAccountCRM. Edit your original question with your VF page.  Then I can help more.

Comment: :I have updated the post VF page and controller.Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: I still don't see why you need a controller to do this, I amended by VF page